# Creating multidimensional arrays from ANTLR grammar

Tags: c#, antlr, interpreter

I'm writing a PLC language interpreter using C#. My interpreter has its own type hierarchy: elemental types (integers, boolean,..) and derived types (structs, arrays,...). I'm having problems while creating multidimensinal arrays from my ANTLR grammar.

This is the way my language declares multidimensional arrays (3x2 int array):

```
TYPE 
    MY_ARRAY : ARRAY [0..2, 1..2] OF INT; 
END_TYPE
```

My antlr grammar for parsing unidimensional array declarations is next:

```
decl_derivated
    : 'TYPE' NEWLINE* ID ':' NEWLINE* type_decl ';' NEWLINE* 'END_TYPE' NEWLINE* -> ^(TYPEDEF<TypeDefinition>[$ID.text, $type_decl.type])
    ;

type_decl returns [Type type]
    : 'STRUCT' NEWLINE* decl_fields 'END_STRUCT' { $type = new STRUCT($decl_fields.fieldList); }
    | 'ARRAY' '[' range ']' 'OF' type_var { $type = new ARRAY($type_var.type, $range.init, $range.end); }   
    ;

range returns [int init, int end]
    : ini=CTE_INT '..' en=CTE_INT { $init = int.Parse($ini.text); $end = int.Parse($en.text); }
    ;

type_var returns [Type type]
    : 'BOOL'  { $type = new BOOL(); }
    | 'INT'   { $type = new INT(); }
    | 'REAL'  { $type = new REAL(); }
    ;

/* lexer */

ID  :   (LETTER | '_') (LETTER | DIGIT | '_')*
    ;

fragment
DIGIT : '0'..'9'
      ;

fragment
INTEGER : DIGIT ('_'|DIGIT)*
    ;

fragment
EXPONENT : ('e'|'E') ('+'|'-')? INTEGER ;

fragment
CTE_INT
    : ('+'|'-'| ) INTEGER
    ;

fragment
CTE_REAL
    : ('+'|'-'| /*vacio*/ ) INTEGER '.' INTEGER EXPONENT?
    ;

RANGE   : '..' ;

RANGE_OR_INT 
    : ( CTE_INT RANGE ) => CTE_INT  { $type=CTE_INT; }
        | ( CTE_REAL )  => CTE_REAL     { $type=CTE_REAL; }
        | CTE_INT                   { $type=CTE_INT; }
    ;

NEWLINE : '\r'? '\n'
    | '\r'
    ;
```

I have no problems to parser multidimensional arrays changing my grammar in array declaration to:

```
type_decl returns [Type type]
        : 'ARRAY' '[' range (',' range)* ']' 'OF' type_var
```

I don't know how to write my constructor for this multidimensional arrays. 
Anyone can help me?
Thank you.

Comment: `decl_array [List<int> listaInit, List<int> listaFin] returns [Type type]
 : 'ARRAY' '[' r1=range {$listaInit.Add($r1.init); $listaFin.Add($r1.end); } 
 (',' r2=range {$listaInit.Add($r2.init); $listaFin.Add($r2.end);})* ']' 'OF' type_var 
 { $type = new ARRAY($type_var.type, $listaInit, $listaFin); } 
 ;` This is way I tried to solve it. Inside the array constructor I create the multidimensional array, but I think It must have been a better way to do it.

Comment: Could you [edit] that into your question? It would be far easier to read. Thanks! (I tried but .. getting the newlines right is more work than I can do well at 3:00am. :)

Comment: I've got a better solution, I'm going to edit my post.

Comment: Now that the eight hours have passed, don't forget to move your answer into an answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Finally, I've achieved a better and more elegant solution. I've added two new methods to my ARRAY data type class: one for adding a new dimension and another one for setting the base type.

```
public class ARRAY : ANY_DERIVED
    {
        public Type de; // ARRAY type
        public int size;
        public int initIndex;
        public int finalIndex;

    public ARRAY(int initIndex, int finalIndex)
    {   
        this.initIndex = initIndex;
        this.finalIndex = finalIndex;
        size = finalIndex - initIndex + 1;
    }

    public void NewDim(int initIndex, int finalIndex)
    {
        if (de == null)
            de = new ARRAY(initIndex, finalIndex);
        else
            ((ARRAY)de).NewDim(initIndex, finalIndex);
    }

    public void SetBaseType(Type t)
    {
        if (de == null)
            de = t;
        else
            ((ARRAY)de).SetBaseType(t);
    }
   }
```

ANTLR grammar:

```
decl_type returns [Type type]
    : 'ARRAY' '[' r1=range {$type = new ARRAY($r1.init, $r1.end);} (',' r2=range {((ARRAY)$type).NewDim($r2.init, $r2.end);})* ']' 'OF' type_var { ((ARRAY)$type).SetBaseType($type_var.type); }    
    ;
```

Anyway, thank you for your time ;)